# How can I resolve these two errors in trigger handler

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class AttachmentTriggerHandler {

    public static void onAfterInsert(List<Attachment> attachments) {

        handleCreditReportAttachments( attachments );  

    }

    public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Attachment> attachments, Map<Id, Attachment> attachmentOldMap) {

        handleCreditReportAttachments( attachments );    

    }


    private static void handleCreditReportAttachments( List<Attachment> attachments) {

        // Get the Credit Report object record prefix  
        String getPrefixOfCreditReport = creditchecker__Credit_Report__c.sobjecttype.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        Set<Id> setAttachmentIds = new Set<Id>(); 
        for( Attachment attachment: attachments ){
            String attachmentParentId = attachment.ParentId;
            String attachmentParentIdPrefix = attachmentParentId.left(3);

            // Add attachment record Id in the set
            if(attachmentParentIdPrefix == getPrefixOfCreditReport) {
                setAttachmentIds.add(attachment.Id);
            }
        }

        // Call the Queueable method so that it makes a callout to Box.com and create the attachment
        if( !setAttachmentIds.isEmpty() ) {

            AsyncBoxAttachment asyncJob = new AsyncBoxAttachment( setAttachmentIds );

            Id jobID = System.enqueueJob(asyncJob);

            System.debug( 'jobID : ' + jobID );


        }     
    }



}
```

I'm getting two errors 1.Invalid type: AsyncBoxAttachment,2.Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void enqueueJob(AsyncBoxAttachment) from the type System.
Please guys help me it is my first trigger.

Comment: The error suggests that you don’t have a class named `AsyncBoxAttachment` implementing a `Queueable`, do you have that?

Answer (score -1):

Seeing the `AsyncBoxAttachment` and the exact error would help. However, here's what I'd check:

- That you defined the `AsyncBoxAttachment` class and that it's accessible to the `AttachmentTriggerHandler.`
- Is it possible that `AttachmentTriggerHandler` is an Inner class? If so, you need to call it as `OuterClass.AttachmentTriggerHandler  = new OuterClass.AttachmentTriggerHandler(setAttachmentIds)`

I think once you fix the `Invalid Type` Exception, the second error will resolve itself

Comment: This one ended up in a review queue today. I think I'll flag this one for the mods to convert to a comment rather than voting to delete (of course, you could do that yourself).